# Starting python with cmd error: Unsupported 16-bit application

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, python, administrator

I'm having trouble running python scripts from my cmd and run environment.
I get an error about an unsupported 16-bit application. After some trial and error I noticed that calling 'py.exe' which should start up python gives me that error.

However, if I start my cmd as admin it doesn't give me the error. The problem is that when I try to run the script from my run environment, it doesn't run as admin so I get the error every time and am therefore unable to use the run environment to start my scripts.

The error I get is the following 
https://prntscr.com/hxu69d

I am running Windows 10, 64 bit and Python 3.6 64 bit.

Does anyone know what might be going wrong and how I can fix it? I'd like to find a way to run the scripts from my the 'run environment (Windows + R)' without getting the error.

Comment: `py.exe` thows the error, so ignore the scripting part. Given that 16 bit support (DOS era stuff!) has been dropped in 64 bit windows I am going to ask the obvious question: Do you have multiple versions of python installed (e.g. one 16 bit interpreter **and** a regular 64 bit interpeter)?  If not sure deinstall python 3.6 64 bit and check if that same c:/users/censored/..../py.exe file still exists.

Answer (score 0):

As general recommendations:

- Check if an additional Python version is installed. Non-required versions should be removed. Python doesn't "upgrade" prior installations and can have multiple versions on a system.
- Do a custom install and put Python into a folder other than the default (but not *C:\Program Files* or *C:\Program Files (x86)*). A path without spaces is recommended. You will probably want to check the option to add Python to your environment variables (though this is typically only for a given user).

For your issue specifically, you may wish to uninstall prior versions of the Python Launcher (*py.exe*) as well (listed under the program manager as a separate entry).

Also note that while using the Python 'Console' Launcher (*py.exe*) isn't terrible, you can (potentially) get the same interactive prompt with just *python* (*.exe*).

Comment: Thank you very much, installing it in a different than default folder seems to have fixed it as well as removing the py launched and reinstalling it.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear it. =)