# Conda suddenly doesn't work, it gives "unsupported 16 bit application" error when I try to run it. How do I fix that?

Tags: python, anaconda

I installed a seperate python version to run on VSCode for seperate project. Conda used to still work, but now suddenly conda doesn't run. What is not running is the python.exe placed on the Anaconda folder. When I try to run that it gives the same error. But I can't even open anaconda navigator, it doesn't open and doesn't give any error message.

I get the following error when I try to run conda on cmd (I did run 'where' commands on python and conda to show where they are. The Python versions are 3.8.12 and 3.10.2)

[image: conda giving error]

One suggestion from this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1283739/starting-python-with-cmd-error-unsupported-16-bit-application)  was to remove other python version. But I need different python versions for different projects.

**How do I fix that? What is the problem?**

My PC is Windows 10 64-bit, a Lenovo laptop.

Comment: What are the different versions of Python you are running?

Comment: Python 3.8.12 and Python 3.10.2, which are placed on the folders python38 and python 310. I don't know which version conda is using as I can't run it. The other python files run without any problem, but conda doesn't run.

Comment: @Coder88 - You will need to determine which version of Anaconda it is and [edit] your question.  You should also specify which version of Python you installed exactly.  We will be unable to help you if you are unable to provide this vital information.  If you need to wipe all versions of Anaconda and Python and download the exact versions you require and update the PATH system environmental variable as appropriate.

Comment: "I installed a seperate python version to run on VSCode for seperate project" - How did you do this?